# Is there a way to use the authentication retrieved from Microsoft Teams (via TeamsFX) and use it for an internal web API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, microsoft-teams

I am currently working on a Tab application for Microsoft Teams and have stumbled upon the extension called [TeamsFx](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx) which enables easy retrieval of an authentication token from Teams without the need of prompting the user every time. Likewise, I used the Teams Toolkit extension for Visual Studio to get started. The project is implemented with .NET 5.0.

What I need, is to use the same authentication token retrieved from Teams inside the tab to then access a web API that is implemented in the same project. I have spent two full days trying to work this issue out with pretty much no result. I can retrieve an authentication token via TeamsFx, but simply using this as the bearer auth token in my web api did nothing but it telling me that the signature was wrong.

I have tried adding something like this to my Startup class:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAd");
```

,but then it threw an exception because the TeamsFx library has already done the same with this call:

```
services.AddTeamsFxSimpleAuth(Configuration);
```

In previous Web API projects I have been able to set up Azure AD authentication to the site, and pretty seemlessly add the [Authorize] tag to any WebAPI classes and it just worked.

I hope that someone can save me from my own insanity ;D

Best,

***//F_***

Comment: I don't have an immediate solution, but this seems like a good candidate for an issue at https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues and we can investigate! (PM @ Microsoft working on Teams Toolkit VS extension)

Comment: @therealjohn I have submitted this on GitHub, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the same question which created in Github, it is already answered and got the solution.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues/1363

Since we only got JavaScript version of microsoft/teamsfx sdk, so we including webpack to wrapper it and using JSRuntime to trigger it in Blazor.
The webpack source code is in JS/src/index.js, you could add these code to get SSO token

```
export async function getSsoToken() {
var credential = new TeamsUserCredential();
var token = await credential.getToken("");
return token;
}
```

Then under JS folder , run 'npm install' and 'npm run build' to webpack the code and refresh the webpack file (wwwroot/teamsfx.js).
Finally you could using JSRuntime trigger the new func you just added in TeamsFx.cs.

```
await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<AccessToken>("TeamsFx.getSsoToken");
```

Comment: From what I can tell this answer need updating as I can't see that Webpack is involved anymore. Am I correct, if so please can you add update the answer or provide a new one.